# Get session data from all connections in Django Channels

Tags: python, django, sockets, websocket, channel

In my Django live time chat app I want to go through all the active connections and retrieve data stored inside `request.session` in each browser. I want to do this when a new connection to the web socket it made.

For example say there is 3 active connections to the chat app;

- Chrome browser; session data - {'username':'Sam'}
- Chrome browser; session data - {'username';'James'}
- Firefox browser; session data - {'username':'Logan'}

I want to get a list of all usernames on `ChatComsumer.connect`. How can I do this?

*consumers.py (connect method)*

```
class ChatComsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
 
    def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'main'
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        #GET ALL USERNAMES HERE.
        self.accept()
```